# I have a problem with this complex numbers equation

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

The question is how many roots $z$ has.
How can i approach this, such that i will be able to solve this kind of problems?
I thought to use de moivre formula. 
How can i apply this here ?

$z^2 = (1-i)\overline{z}$

Comment: You can express $z$ as $re^{i\theta}$ and write $1-i$ in polar form, then equate radius and arguments. Other way is setting $z=x+yi$ and equating real parts and imaginary parts and solving system of equations.

Comment: @Galc127, why didn't my $\bar z$ or $\overline z$ work?

Comment: @abel, it should work, but idan di's post included something before the equation, so it wasn't written as latex. Deleting the spaces solved it.

Answer (score 1):

let $z = r(\cos t + i \sin t),$ then $z^2 = r^2(\cos t + i \sin t), \bar z = r(\cos- t + i \sin -t), 1 - i = \sqrt 2(\cos -\pi/4 + i\sin -\pi/4)$ putting these in the equation gives $$r^2(\cos t + i \sin t)= r \sqrt 2(\cos -t + i \sin -t)(\cos -\pi/4 + i\sin -\pi/4) = r\sqrt 2\left(\cos (-t-\pi/4) +i\sin (-t-\pi/4)\right)$$

the choices for $r$ are $0, \sqrt 2$ and for $t$ is $$t = -t-\pi/4 + 2k\pi$$ which gives $$t = k\pi -\pi/8$$ so there are three solutions $$z = 0, \sqrt 2(\cos 7\pi/8 + i \sin 7\pi/8), \sqrt 2(\cos \pi/8 - i \sin \pi/8).$$

Answer (score 1):

If $$z^2=(1-i)\overline{z}$$ holds then so so does its conjugate:

$$\overline{z}^2=(1+i)z$$ 
multiplying the first by $\overline{z}$ and using the second we get

$$z^2\overline{z}=2z$$

so it follows that $z=0$ or $z\overline{z}=2$ thus multiplying the first by $z$
you have

$$z^3=2(1-i)$$ Now you can use the deMoivre fornula to find $z$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=re^{i\theta}$, hence $z^2=r^2e^{2i\theta} \ \text{and} \ \bar{z}=re^{-i\theta}$. Also, $\displaystyle 1-i=\sqrt{2}e^{\large -\frac{\pi}{4}i}$, thus the equation becomes $\displaystyle r^2e^{2i\theta}=\sqrt{2}e^{\large -\frac{\pi}{4}i}\cdot{re^{-i\theta}}=\sqrt{2}re^{-\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\theta\right)i}$.

Now, equating radius and arguments we get the system $\displaystyle \begin{cases}r^2=\sqrt{2}r \\ \frac{\pi}{4}=-\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta+2\pi k\\\end{cases}$.

It shouldn't be a problem to solve it.